# How to get diameter of inner ring in pie highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, height, pie-chart

I can get diameter of external ring by plotHeight but is there any way to get diameter of inner ring of pie highchart? (https://jsfiddle.net/noy986m7/23/)

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
        type: 'pie',
    },
    series: [{
        innerSize: "40%",
        data: [{
            y: 70.67,
        }, {
            y: 14.77
        }]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variable-pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const getInnerDiameter = (series) => {
    const r = [];
    series.forEach((item) => {
        item.data.forEach(point => {
            r.push(point.shapeArgs.innerR);
        });
    });
    return Math.min(...(r.filter(Boolean))) * 2;
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
        type: 'pie',
                events: {
            load: function () {
               console.log("externelD: " + this.plotHeight, "innerD: " + getInnerDiameter(this.series))
            },
        },
    },
    series: [{
        innerSize: "40%",
        data: [{
            y: 70.67,
        }, {
            y: 14.77
        }]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variable-pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `innerSize` with percentage you can approximate the diameter with `chart.plotHeight * (innerSize / 100)` where e.g. `innerSize = 40`.

For example ([see this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kvgd2c/)):

```
const innerSize = 40

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
  },
  series: [{
    innerSize: `${innerSize}%`,
    data: [70.67,14.77]
  }]
}, function(chart) {
  const diameter = chart.plotHeight * (innerSize / 100)
  const radius = diameter / 2

  const center = chart.series[0].center
  const centerCircle = [
    center[0] + chart.plotLeft,
    center[1] + chart.plotTop,
    radius
  ]

  const circle = chart.renderer.circle(...centerCircle)
    .attr({
      fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)',
      zIndex: 3
    })
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      circle.attr('fill', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.0');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      circle.attr('fill', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4');
    })
    .add();
});
```

As you can see from the fiddle there appears to be a very minor overlap. I'm unsure of the source of this overlap, but the approximation is quite good.